# How to Sort Values in Rails Drop Down

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a dropdown with options_from_collection_for_select tag.I want to have the values in the dropdown list sorted by ascending order. (it's a list of cusromer names,just want them sorted by customer name in ascending order). This is what I have:

```
.row
 .col-md-3
   = label_tag "Customer/Supplier Name"
   = select_tag "search_customer_supplier[id]", options_from_collection_for_select(Organization.customers_and_suppliers, :id, :name, params.dig('search_customer_supplier', 'id')), class: "form-control parent_class chosen-select", id: "search_registered_customers", include_blank: true
```

In my model the customers_and_suppliers method difined as a scope. Here it is

```
 scope :customers_and_suppliers, -> { joins(accounts_dealer_types: :dealer_type).where(mst_dealer_types: {code: Organization::TYPES}) }
```

Finally i tried using this code

```
scope :customers_and_suppliers, -> { joins(accounts_dealer_types: :dealer_type).where(mst_dealer_types: {code: Organization::TYPES}).order('name ASC') }
```

Then i got the results as ascending order.But in the dropdown there are so many duplicated records displaying,What will be the solution ?

Comment: How did you define `customers_and_suppliers` method, show that..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Above i attached the method.

Comment: add a `.uniq` in your scope ?

Comment: @morissetcl Oh god it helped me to solve the problem. Thank u sir !